# Does PHP File Upload work on all devices

Tags: php, html, file-upload, mobile, mobile-website

I am curious as to know if the **basic PHP File Upload procedure** will work on all devices. 
Such as:

- All Major Browsers
- Mobile Phones (iPhone, Blackberry, Android, Palm)

I need to be able to upload Videos/Photos from any device onto our server, will there be any issues that you can forsee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser doesn't "SEE" PHP....php is server side code.  The interaction on the front end might happen with flash (often used in "ajax-styled" uploads") javascript, and/or html.  HTML is about as basic as it gets, so 99% of the devices out there can deal with it.

Just imagine the chaos if we had to coordinate our browsers with the back-end technology.  It's tough enough as it is with the lack of current standards and half-decade-in-the-dark browser team that does IE....thanks Microsoft.....

I'd personally caution you against using bleeding-edge technology such as CSS3 or HTML5 if you're trying to make something "universally" compatible.  For example, AOL's browser, which is still in use, believe it or not, is essentially an old version of IE6.  Some of the phone browsers are even more basic, though I'd question whether people would ever REALLY use those in an upload situation.  It's not fun to use "old" technology, but especially when clients are very specific about backwards compatibility, you often don't have a choice.

Answer (score 4):

First Off, PHP is not the one that handles file uploads, that dependent on the browser and how they handle it. The browser is the one sending the information about the file (contents, size, type)

Second, mobile platforms will not do this well. iPhone doesn't allow file uploads from their browser. I'm not sure on android, but iPhone alone should be enough to re-think this.

Comment: That sucks about iPhone. So essentially you would have to create a native app to enable iPhones to upload files right? Would using a framework (ie: PhoneGap) be a better solution for that?